# What are the benefits and the disadvantages of creating a protected constructor of a Class

Tags: java, constructor, protected

I have a silly doubt, but I would like to hear some opinions about it.

I have a super class (MySuperClass), and then, I have like 70 classes inheriting from this super class (Bean classes).

The purpose of this super class is to implement the "toString" method using reflection, and this way, I'm making sure that all of this 70 classes will have the toString method. These 70 classes are beans, and the final purpose is to log the class information instead of just the instance of the class.

However, that is not what I want to discuss, what I would like to hear from you is what do you think about having a protected constructor for the superclass, benefits and disadvantages of having this, and not only for this particular case but for other situations or scenarios that you can imagine.

Regards,

Fer

Answer (score 6):

If your goal is to ensure that `MySuperClass` is never instantiated directly via `new MySuperClass()`, only its subclasses are, then it makes more sense to declare the class `abstract`; see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html. That's really the whole point of abstract classes. The constructor can then be either `public` or `protected`, it doesn't really matter.

The reason to have all constructors `protected` in a *non*-`abstract` class would be if you *do* intend to instantiate the class itself, using `new MySuperClass()`, but only want it to be instantiated *by* subclasses and other members of its package (such as a "factory" object). That doesn't sound like what you're trying to do, though.

Comment: Well, the goal of declare the constructor as protected is to disallow public instantiation of my superclass. But I wanted to hear some opinions about this.

Comment: @FernandoMoyano: Right, but *why* do you want to disallow public instantiation of your superclass? It sounds like what you *really* want -- or really *should* want -- is to disallow any direct instantiation of your superclass at all. That is, it sounds like the class is useless except *as* a superclass, and there's no reason ever to have an instance of this superclass that's not an instance of one of its subclasses.

Comment: Thanks @ruakh, I think you have described with accuracy what I want to do: "... to disallow any direct instantiation of your superclass at all. That is, it sounds like the class is useless except as a superclass, and there's no reason ever to have an instance of this superclass that's not an instance of one of its subclasses ..."

Comment: @FernandoMoyano: Then, that means you want an abstract class. See the link in my answer. :-)

Answer (score 1):

if u want to create only one instance using a static method that return an instance of this type you can make the constructor protected. benefits memory allocation when the object is to heavy and creating many instances will affect the memory

```
public class A{
   private static A instance = null;
   protected A() {
      // Exists only to defeat instantiation.
   }
   public static A getInstance() {
      if(instance == null) {
         instance = new A();
      }
      return instance;
   }
}
```

Comment: Class B in the same package can say `A a = new A();`.  Byebye goes your singleton.

Comment: Hi@HusseinX, thanks for your answer. I'm not looking for a singleton, @ruakh has correctly described what I want to do.

Answer (score 1):

A protected constructor has one useful trait that isn't available with abstract classes: classes in the same package, subclasses, and static methods within the class itself can create instances of the class, while outsiders can't.  Abstract classes can't be instantiated at all, regardless of the constructor's accessibility.

With that said, i would prefer to have the class be abstract.  Protected constructors can't prevent a subclass, or any class in the same package, from saying `BaseClass x = new BaseClass();`.  A protected constructor says to me "The code may be instantiating this class somewhere", and gives me yet another thing to have to keep track of.

Comment: Hi @cHao, thanks for our answer. This can not be an abstract class, because it implements the to string method using reflection.

Comment: There's some limitation on reflection in abstract classes?  News to me... Abstract classes should have all the same capabilities as non-abstract ones, excluding of course the ability to be instantiated.

Comment: Ooops, you're right, I've just tested and it works pretty fine. I was sure that it was not possible. Thanks @cHao